# CSS DIV with Cross Browser Opaque Border with Solid background

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, opacity

Is it possible to achieve cross browser (ie6+) semi-transparent borders with a solid background on div?

I have only found instances where:

- Borders are semi-transparent, but so is background.
- Body is semi-transparent, but borders are not.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, or an alternative solution?

Comment: Hm... *solid* and *opaque* means the same thing in this context...

Comment: hey now check to this link i think you want to this http://jsfiddle.net/gf5Fd/

Comment: @Guffa I guess the OP meant transparent;)

Comment: If you google your question, here is the first link that pops up: [Css Transparent Borders](http://css-tricks.com/transparent-borders-with-background-clip/)

Comment: Have you made progress with your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on which browsers you want/have to support, but you can use the CSS3-rgba declaration to define colors (standard rgb with additional `a` - which is the alpha/transparency channel). Also, depending on the colors of the background and border, you might need to add the `background-clip` property.

```
rgba(255,255,255,.5);
background-clip:padding-box;
```

would give you an 50% opaque white. This works on every attribute you can specify a color on.

It's pretty good [supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba) with the (how surprising) exception of IE<=8.

Here is an example for you: [transparent border with solid bg](http://jsfiddle.net/Nwh24/1/).

For the sake of completeness: The necessary background-clip has the same browsersupport, but here is a [browser support table](http://www.standardista.com/css3/css3-background-properties/)

EDIT:

For support for IE6+ you should take a look at [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/). It emulates CSS3 Properties like rounded corners or other color spaces via VML.

Comment: @c0D3l0g1c then you definitely should take a look into http://css3pie.com/ - It uses VML as fallback for the old IEs.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the age of browser you need to support, [background-clip](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-origin-and-background-clip/) could be a good solution.

You'd want to use `padding-box` and then set the background colour and border colour to whatever you need, using `rgba(0,0,0,0)` for any semi-transparent values with the 4th value being the alpha.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey now you can used to `rgba properties` in **background color** and **border solid** as like this

**CSS**

```
.parent{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 50px;
}

.box {
    background: #f0edcc;
    border: 24px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="box">Your message.</div>
</div>
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/gf5Fd/1/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make this work in MSIE6: semi-transparent borders with opaque backgrounds:

```
.qm { 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("trans_paars70.png");
    padding: 1em;
}
```

Basically, I use the element's *padding* to create a *fake border*, which gets filled with the semi-transparent background image (this works just fine in MSIE6 as long as you provide a 256-color paletted gif or png).